# Swipe with Appium using Java is not possible in ios apps

Tags: ios, appium, swipe, appium-ios

When I'm trying for swipe operation in ios apps it is showing this error.

> [org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Unknown command, all
>   the mobile commands except scroll have been removed. (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information).]

please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of the error the method you are using is not implemented in appium. How are you calling it?

I am able to swipe in my iPhone (9.3.5) using xcode 8 (XCUI driver type) using the command:

`driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration`

Where the above 4 arguments are positions on the screen, and duration is the length of the swipe (make sure to use a short one as a duration that is too long will cause the iOS magnifying glass to appear)

If that doesn't work you should specify the following information:

Appium Build:

XCode Build (If applicable):

Device and OS: